# Passing Information at the End of Command Path

Tags: .net, visual-studio, batch-file, cmd

I'm working with an old program that uses a built-in version of IE6 as the browser. There is a customizable toolbar in this program that allows you to open HTML links or open External Programs with variables added to the end.

We built a Web App to view information external information easily from this program and open the current customer (via ID). The URL is structured like so:

```
http://website.com/htmlpage1.html?inpUserId=92849
```

Via the "External Program" option, the User ID (92849) is raw output at the end of the field. So it would be structured as so:

```
c:\open.bat?UserID=92849 (The 92849 dynamically being populated by the program)
```

What we're trying to do is open the information in Chrome:

```
start chrome http://website.com/Portal/User?userId=%UserID%
```

Obviously, that doesn't work. We're looking for a way to pass the raw Customer ID and insert it into the URL opened in Chrome.

Comment: so are you looking to prompt the user for an ID value and then run the bat file? You can read input from user in the .bat (if you didn't know). Otherwise except for passing in a value from the cmd line, like `c:\bat\myBat.bat "input"` and then transfering to that like `userID = %1%` I don't understand your use case.  (sorry if my  `bat` syntax isn't perfect, I only very occasionally use it now). Rather than reply in comments, add additional information to your Q so all readers will get you use case just from reading your Q. Good luck.

Comment: I changed by verbiage a bit. Essentially, the CustomerID is output raw at the end of the field dynamically, and we need a way to insert that into a URL that will open in another browser.

Comment: it sounds like you want the `.cmd` equivalent of the `bash` shell's (and others) command-substitution and you might need an `eval` too. Try searching for these terms in a `.bat` context. I know the `.bat` language got a lot more features after I stopped using it with it DOS3 set of features. Is there a `bat` tag with a lot of followers you can add to your Q? Good luck.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a .bat, open to any solution that can accept raw data at the end. Never have needed such a simple workaround before.

Comment: Can you use a *nix (like) command line (WSL, cygwin, Linux)? Then no sweat. `chrome "https://example.com/Portal/User\?userID=(external_program
_that_produces_UserID_output [opt_args])"` , should work. Worst case would require prepending `eval` as the first word to that command, but `eval` leaves you open to serious hacking issues. Search here, you'll find plenty about why not `eval`. Hopefully you recognize the `[opt_args]` convention for specifying options to a program. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't. The program is super old and passes the variable as the number itself. It then opens its own version of IE6 that has its own security issues.

Comment: But given the tags you have included, your audience for readers that watch Qs by the tags for their area of interest, you're are aimed at Windows users. Maybe add `dot-net` (or what ever the correct tag is) or VisualBasic? So  as I think there's a pretty good chance that newer `.bat` files can do what you need, I urging you to include any tag with more than 500 followers, in hopes that regular readers will see and solve your problem. Saw your most recent comment, all the more reason to be sure your tags are getting you the readers you need. Good luck!

Comment: `WSL` is a linux that works under Windows 10 (just to be clear). Good luck.

Comment: Don't understand. You have a program that outputs `c:\open.bat?UserID=92849` and you want to extract the number?